# MVC form data submission to controller

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I am managing to deploy a very simple implementation, containing a registration form and for demonstration purposes, I have chosen to use the MVC pattern.

My slight issue is that when I press the submit button, I want the submitted data to be handled by the suitable method of the controller.

For instance:

within the view part, I declare the form like this :

```
<form action="controller/validate" method="post"/>
```

I am assuming that this is a routing-related thing, but I am curious whether another way can be suggested.

--

Regards,

Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A router can be as simple as a switch statement instead of a full blown router for the small sites:

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case 'controller/validate':
        $view = new \Views\User\Registration();
        $controller = new \Controllers\UserRegistration($view);
        $method = 'validate';
        break;

    default:
        $view = new \Views\Error\NotFound();
        $controller = new \Controllers\Error($view);
        $method = 'notFound';
        break;
}

echo $controller->$method();
```

Also note that instead of doing a relative URL based on the current path you often really want to do a relative URL to the document root:

```
<form action="/controller/validate" method="post"/>
```

Note the leading slash.

<sub>*The above is just a simple (untested) example of semi pseudocode*</sub>

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Long-time framework users (like me) seem to tend to overcomplicate things when thinking about bare PHP.

Comment: Yes, it won't be a complicated build, therefore your reply  is very close to my requirement. Would you suggest to create it as astandalone file ( in terms of not being a controller), integrate it within the index.php, or following another way ?

Comment: @thitami Whenever I am using above I am doing this in my bootstrap file (basically the index.php file in most applications). The bootstrap file does all the possible initialization for the application to function.

Comment: I would probably put it into something like `bootstrap.php` and include it `index.php`. But then again, I would care for future expansions (like multiple front-controllers - maybe `debug.php`). In your case, `index.php` will probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your help is really appreciated.
I accept PeeHaa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would make your *controller* accessible through a *route* (like `POST /register`). A controller action is assigned to this route in a bootstrap file. Some pseudo-code:

```
$framework->route('GET', '/register',
                  'RegistrationController::action_form');
$framework->route('POST', '/register',
                  'RegistrationController::action_submit');
```

Another aproach would be mapping routes directly to controllers (some frameworks do this, I believe *Kohana* is one of them) like this:

- Route: `/register/submit`
- Resolves to: `RegisterContoller::action_submit()`
- Management of request method (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` in standard HTTP) happens in the action methods.

Comment: Thanks for that, Lukas. What I am currently looking for, is to find if there is a shorter alternative way to routing.

Comment: @thitami That would then be closest to the second way I mentioned. _Routing_ is just a name for something; you always have to somehow assign controllers to requests. My suggestion would be to automatically map requests like this: `/<Class>/<Method>` maps to `<Class>Controller::action_<Method>()`. Note the `Controller` suffix and `action_` prefix for the names. This avoids other classes or methods (like `InternalClass::do_something_internally()`) to be called by the public.